# Pointers and arrays reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference, memory-address

In the textbook, there are some codes and explanation

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int *byte_pointer;
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len){
int i;
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    printf(" |%.2x",start[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x){
show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}
```

It says the reference start[i] indicates that we want to read the byte that is i position **beyond** the location pointed to by start.

Is it correct that (ex. int type) pointer has int type(4 byte) so it read 4 byte (ex. address of 0x100~0x103) or end of data **even though we just give a starting point address** (ex.0x100)? Am I correct?

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Please don't typedef pointer.

Comment: If this code is taken from your textbook verbatim, you should demand your tuition fees back.

Comment: An `int` is not a byte. Beyond obfuscating the code, that typedef is also lying to the person reading it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `start[i]` gets the value at memory cell `start + sizeof(int) * i` which is most probably not what you (or the author of the textbook) want.

You have to replace

```
typedef int *byte_pointer;
```

by

```
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
```

Then `start[i]` gives you the i-th memory cell after `start` because `sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The names of this example are ill fitting.
The arithmetic of pointers is done by the sizeof the type of element the pointer set to.
if the pointer is:

type* ptr;

then each ptr[i] will place you at the location the pointer is pointing to plus i*(sizeof(type));

type can be char, int, long, size_t an so on. it depends on the type of data you are pointing to. if you are pointing to a char array for example- the sizeof(char) is one byte. so to get to the second element you need to get to the init. location and move one byte over to read one byte of data, which is the second element.